# compare mysql id between 2 table and display all with match id echo yes

Tags: php, mysql

I want to compare mysql id between 2 table and display all name with match id echo yes.

I have 2 table one is wine and the other is user. I will use unique id column from table wine. But in table user, I will use wine_id column which are not unique.

This is mysql code that will get a matching id from table wine and user.

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM `winelist` w WHERE page = 'Chardonnay USA' and
EXISTS(
SELECT wine_id FROM `user_wine_history` u WHERE user_name = 'bon'
AND u.wine_id = w.id);";
$result= mysql_query($sql);

while($data= mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
}
```

and this is the code for for listing all the name in wine.

```
$sql2 ="SELECT id, name, year, grape, price, instock FROM winelist WHERE page ='Chardonnay USA';";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
}
```

I tried to use this code in listing name while loop but it didn't work.

```
if($data2['id'] == $data['id']) {
echo "yes";
}
else
{ 
echo "fail";
}
```

Can anybody give me some advice how to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` instead and do this within the query using the `CASE` expression, something like:

```
SELECT 
  w.id , w.page, w.name, w.year, 
  u.user_name, u.id user_id, u.wine_id uwine_id,
  CASE 
    WHEN u.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' 
    ELSE 'No' 
  END AS IsMatching
FROM `winelist` w 
LEFT JOIN `user_wine_history` u  ON w.id        = u.wine_id 
                                AND w.page      = 'Chardonnay USA' 
                                AND u.user_name = 'bon';
```

This will select a new column `IsMatching` with values `yes` or `no` to indicate whether the wine `id` is found in the other table or not.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc5bef/7)

Comment: I think this is what I look for. But as I echo out in while loop, nothing come out. I tried echo $data['id'];  what did I do wrong?

Comment: @Jack - the query should work fine as you can see in the sql fiddle demo, it might be a problem in your php code, try to update your question and show your full code with tthe new query. also note that you are expecting a new column `IsMatching`m you have to echo it as well. And try first to run the query directly in MySQL workbench or PHPMyAdmin and ensure it is working fine.

Comment: I try it in PHPMyAdmin. It works. I guess I just don't know how to  query it out.

Comment: I put your code in $sql then $ result=mysql_query($ sql); while ($data=mysql_fetch_array ($ result)){echo $ data['id'];}

Comment: Working now. THANK You. I think something wrong with my server. I added a where clause at the end of your code so it displays only from page chardonnay usa. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Join**:

> $id= Here the input

```
SELECT id FROM `winelist` w  
INNER JOIN `user_wine_history` u 
ON u.wine_id = w.id
WHERE w.page = 'Chardonnay USA' AND u.user_name = 'bon'
AND w.id = '".$id."'
```

Comment: I try echo id but nothing come out. But from my understanding this will echo only match I'd right?